# Can saltstack update itself then run highstate

Tags: mercurial, version-control, automatic-updates

salt stack is being used with bit bucket. there are 2-3 of us who push updates to it occasionaly. I was wondering is there a way where salt stack can get the latests changes from bit bucket then highstate? if so how would you go about doing so.

Answer (score 0):

If bitbucket supports something similar to git-hooks then your could write a hook to fire an event which causes the salt master to update its copy of the code and to run a highstate on your minion.

http://docs.saltstack.com/topics/reactor/